# Creating an object that behaves similarly to a string constant pool

Tags: java, string

I was doing some reading on Strings and came across [this](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/the-string-class.php) article. Specifically, this section:

> As applications grow, it's very common for String literals to occupy large amounts of a program's memory, and there is often a lot of redundancy within the universe of String literals for a program. To make Java more memory efficient, the JVM sets aside a special area of memory called the "String constant pool." When the compiler encounters a String literal, it checks the pool to see if an identical String already exists. If a match is found, the reference to the new literal is directed to the existing String, and no new String literal object is created.

I was wondering if it was possible to create an object that had a similar behavior, where it would check if another object existed that was equivalent to it, and would then reference the existing data. I attempted to model this with a bank account system. The user would be able to create a bank account with just an account number as instance data. If the account number already existed, it would assign the object to reference to the pre-existing object, instead of creating a new one. My original idea was to use a static array to hold all the objects, call each object in the constructor, and then compare their account numbers to decide if they were duplicates. However, before I got to that stage, I realized that I wasn't able to reassign the object reference in a method of that object:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    int accountNumber;
    String name;
    BankAccount previousAccount; //instead of an array, I first tested with one value
    BankAccount currentAccount;

    BankAccount(int actNum){
        currentAccount = this;
        if(actNum == previousAccount.getAccountNumber())
            this = currentAccount;  
    }    

    public int getAccountNumber(){
        return accountNumber;  
    }    

}
```

My specific issue was that I wasn't able to assign a new value to `this` and I received the error message: "Cannot assign a value to final variable this." I looked into the issue and realized I wouldn't be able to change the reference by retargeting this. Furthermore, if I were to pass the object name in as a parameter, I would then only be changing the reference of the formal parameter, not the original object. In short my questions are the following:

- How would you change the reference of an object in a method it calls upon itself (non-static).
- How would you make an object behave like a String in terms of memory storage (a general description would be perfect. I understand that my attempt doesn't come close and I am not asking for the code to be written for me, just a general guideline would be appreciated).

Comment: Here's a hint: when's the last time you directly called the `String` constructor?

Comment: So I understand that I'm calling a String literal: "For the “literal” String assignment if the assignment value is identical to another String assignment value created then a new String object is not created. A reference to the existing String object is returned. Below picture explains this concept. " What I'm not sure of is how to do something like that for an object I create.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may be interested in Guava's [`Interners`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html).

Comment: You need a static factory method, so it can check if object already exists or if a new object needs to be created. Tracking of objects should likely be done using a `Map`.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. That pretty much answered my question.

Comment: On a side note so in your bank i can basically own anyone's account just by requesting you to create a new account with an existing id :)

Comment: @EricWiener This only works for string **literals**, not for `new String(...)` expressions. Literals are a language feature. You cannot make any new kind of literal yourself.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is commonly known as the flyweight pattern. Have a look at wikipedia and the examples given there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern